# Ionic 3 Ion-Input clearOnEdit doesn't work first time input box is focused

Tags: input, ionic3

Ionic has several attributes with their ion-input box.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.1/api/components/input/Input/

One of them is the clearOnEdit which clears the box when a user begins editing. However, if the ion-input box already has data in it when the page is loaded, the clearOnEdit attribute doesn't work the first time you click on it.

```
<ion-label text-left text-wrap>Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input text-right 
               type="number"
               step="0.01"
               clearOnEdit="true"
               value="3.4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item no-padding no-margin>
    <ion-label text-left text-wrap>Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input text-right 
               type="number"
               step="0.01"
               clearOnEdit="true"
               value="3.4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item no-padding no-margin>
    <ion-label text-left text-wrap>Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input text-left 
               type="number"
               step="0.01"
               clearOnEdit="true"
               value="3.4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

It will clear the box every other time it's brought into focus but is there a way to make it work the first time too?